# Beaglebone Bluetooth

Tags: python-2.7

I need help with setting up my BeagleBone Black + Adafruit Bluefruit friend LE to communicate over BLE. My goal is to connect the Bluefruit to my BeagleBone so I can scan any Bluetooth device available and try to connect to it. So, I downloaded `Adafruit_Python_BluefruitLE` and I am trying to use the example `uart_service.py` but every time I run it I get the following error:

> File "uart_service.py", line 85, in ble.run_mainloop_with(main)
>   File "build/bdist.linux-arm71/egg/Adafruit_BluefruitLE/bluez_dbus/provider.py", line 105, in run_mainloop_with
>
> File "build/dbist.linux-arm71/egg/Adafruit_BluefruitLE/bluez_dbus/provider.py" , line 120, in _user_thread_main
>
> File "uart_service.py", line 24, in main
>   adapter.power_on()
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'power_on"

Please help me to resolve this.

https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-adafruit-ble-bluetooth-low-energy-friend/introduction

Comment: You better ask at the adafruit forums.

Comment: I asked and they said to go to a different website. I found this to be my best chance to get a response.

Comment: did you used bluez5